# Find Journaling errors in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, journal, journaling

My client is using office365 and I have setup journaling for some of their mailboxes. But as it seems some of the emails they have received, have not been sent to the journal mailbox.

I checked on transaction rules, but those were fine.

What other reasons can course this kind of an error?

Is there a log file which I can check to find Journaling errors?

> This doesn't happen for all the emails, only for some of the emails,
>   so there should not be any issue with journal configuration, right?

I only have access to PowerShell, can't log in to their real accounts or admin portals.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue, the client has set up his own email address as the NDR email box, which he set up for journaling as well.

When a user does such a thing office 365 pop up a warning as below. Changing the email into some other email resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Also, within my investigation, I found out that if the user sets the journal recipient email box as the NDR email box, this kind of issue can occur as well.

On UI NDR email is = "Send undeliverable journal reports to"